# delete duplication in my db with 4 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 columns with different numbers, each row is a different combination, my objective is to remove remove the duplicates in the table. 
As these are combinations where the order of the digits is swapped, i want to remove the swapped rows and keep only 1 (i'm guessing each 4 numbers set will have 24 different options in the table, so i'll need to delete 23 and keep only 1)

Table name: "4_numbers"

```
-------------------------
|id | e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 |
-------------------------
| 1 |  1 |  5 |  3 |  7 |
| 2 |  1 |  5 |  7 |  9 |
| 3 |  5 |  1 |  7 |  3 |
-------------------------
```

so i need to delete one of the row that has a duplicate combination. for example one of the rows 1 or 3

here is what i tried, but its going into a infinite loop, i am sure something is wrong with my query.

```
<?php

    $sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mysql");
    if (!$sql) {
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("combs");

      $result = mysql_query("delete b from 4_even a join 4_even b on (a.e1 = b.e2 and a.e2 = b.e2 and a.e3 = b.e4 and a.e4 = b.e4) or (a.e2 = b.e1 and a.e1 = b.e2 and a.e4 = b.e3 and a.e3 = b.e4) where a.id < b.id;");

      echo "success";
    if (!$result) {
        die("Could not delete. " . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

my query is an adaptation of another query i used earlier to remove duplicates from a table of 2 columns and not 4, it worked perfectly with it. so i just need to adapt it to support 4 columns.

```
mysql_query("delete b from 4_numbers a join 4_numbers b on (a.e1 = b.e2 and a.e2 = b.e2) or (a.e2 = b.e1 and a.e1 = b.e2) where a.id < b.id;")
```

Comment: **NOTE** The `mysql_*` api is deprecated and dropped as of PHP 7.0. Consider using the [PDO MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do with a query like this.

1) create a temp table
2) insert all unique row in temp
3) rename table ( is atomic) so the application not fails

```
CREATE  TABLE tmp_4_even LIKE 4_even;

INSERT INTO tmp_4_even
SELECT e2.* FROM (
        SELECT id FROM (
            SELECT min(id) AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(e1 SEPARATOR '-')  AS g
            FROM ( SELECT id,e1  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e2  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e3  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e4  FROM 4_even
            ORDER BY id,e1
        ) AS res
        GROUP BY id
    ) res2
    GROUP BY g 
) e1
LEFT JOIN 4_even e2 ON e1.id = e2.id;

RENAME TABLE 4_even TO 4_even_org, tmp_4_even TO 4_even;
```

**sample inner query**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (
    -> SELECT min(id) AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(e1 SEPARATOR '-')  AS g
    -> FROM ( SELECT id,e1  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e2  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e3  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e4  FROM 4_even
    -> ORDER BY id,e1
    -> ) AS res
    -> GROUP BY id
    -> ) res2
    -> GROUP BY g ;
+------+---------+
| id   | g       |
+------+---------+
|    1 | 1-3-5-7 |
|    4 | 5-7-1-5 |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from 4_even;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | e1   | e2   | e3   | e4   |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    5 |    3 |    7 |
|  2 |    1 |    5 |    7 |    3 |
|  3 |    5 |    1 |    7 |    3 |
|  4 |    5 |    1 |    7 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> CREATE  TABLE tmp_4_even LIKE 4_even;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO tmp_4_even
    -> SELECT e2.* FROM (
    -> SELECT id FROM (
    -> SELECT min(id) AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(e1 SEPARATOR '-')  AS g
    -> FROM ( SELECT id,e1  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e2  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e3  FROM 4_even UNION ALL SELECT id,e4  FROM 4_even
    -> ORDER BY id,e1
    -> ) AS res
    -> GROUP BY id
    -> ) res2
    -> GROUP BY g
    -> ) e1
    -> LEFT JOIN 4_even e2 ON e1.id = e2.id;
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql>
mysql> RENAME TABLE 4_even TO 4_even_org, tmp_4_even TO 4_even;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from 4_even;
+----+------+------+------+------+
| id | e1   | e2   | e3   | e4   |
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    5 |    3 |    7 |
|  4 |    5 |    1 |    7 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: thanks for the long reply amazing, but do you think i can just edit this query as it was working perfectly with the 2 columns and make it work for 4 columns ?
`mysql_query("delete b from 4_numbers a join 4_numbers b on (a.e1 = b.e2 and a.e2 = b.e2) or (a.e2 = b.e1 and a.e1 = b.e2) where a.id < b.id;")`
thanks again